# Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: sal: sal

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I found this error whenever i try to start my tomcat server from intellij idea.I tried by adding hostname on my hosts file (i.e etc/hosts) but it didn't work for me.screenshot of host file has been added here where "sal" is my hostname. Is there anyone who can help me out of this problem?[image]

Comment: Just use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Are you trying to make the server listen/bind and address specified by `sal` or are you trying to connect to a service (such as a database) on `sal`

Comment: @MartinKonecny : I am just trying to run my project on tomcat

Comment: But what is `sal` being used for? Please show it's use in some context. There's two different answers based on how you're using it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I tried that too but i am getting same error repeatedly. No idea what is happening.

Comment: Is it already running? How are you starting tomcat?

Comment: @MartinKonecny: sal is my computer name. As i got "local host name unknown" error, I tried to add my hostname on local host. Thats it.

Comment: Are you sure `sal` isn't in your code somewhere?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I can run tomcat from command. It is working but not working fom intellij idea

Comment: @MartinKonecny: YES, i am sure. sal is just a hostname whic i added later.

Comment: OK you're right. My last suggestion is to open up a command prompt, and type `hostname`. This will verify whether the actual hostname is "sal".

Comment: @MartinKonecny: this is verified martin. I don't know why this isn't working

Comment: can you do `ping sal` from the command prompt? what about `ping 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @MartinKonecny: yes, I can ping the sal from my cmd

Comment: It could also be possible ports are open for localhost in Windows firewall

Comment: tried the solutions. Still unable to solve the problem. just can't find a way

Comment: @NIteshShrestha If you're on a *NIX machine, you could try flushing dscacheutil - `dscacheutil -flushcache` after adding to the hosts file.